# Cat 5e Wire Next to 12V

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, wiring

I'm currently running a consumer grade router from inside a closet, and want to switch to business grade equipment. So the plan is to place a wireless access point *on* the wall outside of said closet and run the cat 5e and the 12v dc power for the ap through the wall together. So they will be next to each other for about 5 or 6 inches. Is this likely to cause problems with inductance? Since the ap can handle PoE, and the router (and for that matter any switch I will be likely to replace it with) cannot, I am concerned about frying my router.

Should I just bite the bullet and buy a PoE injector, or am I safe to run the wires as planned?

Comment: Auto-correct. I meant on the wall.

Comment: 12 volts AC or 12 volts DC?

Comment: DC. Updated question to reflect.

Comment: Low-voltage DC will produce a steady (but weak) magnetic field that should not cause any problems.  AC line voltage is the type of power cable to worry about.  Note that use of wires/cables not rated for in-wall installation will probably violate local building codes.  Flammability of the PVC/vinyl insulation is a concern.

Comment: sawdust - If you make your last comment an answer, I'll call solve the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low-voltage DC will produce a steady (but weak) magnetic field that should not cause any problems with Ethernet cable.  A 12VDC wire should cause no more issues than the 48VDC typically used with PoE.
AC line voltage (e.g. 120VAC) is the type of power cable to worry about.

Note that use of wires/cables not rated for in-wall installation will probably violate local building codes.  Flammability of the PVC/vinyl insulation is a concern

Answer (score 0):

You are technically safe to run the CAT-5 cable and low voltage power together through the wall as the safety risks are near zero, although this may still be a fire code violation.

The 12vDC connections would not have any impact on the Ethernet connection.

The proper way to do this would be to use a PoE injector/adapter, which is relatively inexpensive and can be purchased from major online retailers for under $20 and in some cases under $10. Using this in the closet would allow for a single properly rated cable to come through the wall.

Comment: My father-in-law is a general contractor and had told me there is no code violation, but I wanted to make sure that I wouldn't get inductance. I wouldn't mind using PoE, but I would prefer to put that $20 into some other equipment.

Comment: @oran0007 I can tell you that as a technician by trade, if I did this I would be written up... Every locality has different laws, in the Dakotas or Minnesota, this would be a violation. It your project, do it the way you wish. From a technical standpoint it shouldn't be a problem.